# Extracting values from Json which could possibly be null or non-existent

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON response in Java which I have converted to Java object using Jackson libray. I have to extract specific large number of values from the JSON... say 10th element in an unbounded array... an attribute from an object in the object tree which may not exist/null. The problem I face is since I have to extract large number of values from JSON (about 500), I have to do a huge number of null checks which makes my code look bulky & clumsy. Is there a clean way of handling the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`JsonNode.path()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#path(java.lang.String)) methods. They should allow traversal without having to check each step.

Comment: JsonNode.path() seems to be useful (not needing null checks). But is there a way to handle it in Java? I think handling it in pojo will decouple json from the attributes. In case the json keys change, i just have to change the annotation on top of my attribute/class.